# Website to read file on diff raspberry pi and display values based on variable

Tags: php, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to create a website and 2 raspberry pi's that will connect to the website.

The goal is:
rpiA's display will be different from rpiB.

I'll put a file on each rpi containing their name. When I visit the website using rpiA, rpiA's name will be displayed (vice versa).

What I did is I placed a file in var/www/html/name.php

```
<?php

$xname= 'RPI-001';

echo $xname;

?>
```

Then on the website I placed:

```
$device_name = file_get_contents('http://127.0.0.1/name.php');
echo $device_name;
```

However, the result is always empty. I checked the allow_url_fopen and it is On. The reason maybe the 127.0.0.1 is broad and it needs a specific ip?
I also tried curl but the result is Error 404.

Is there another way to do this?

I did not consider login or session since I'm using a small screen in rpi and it will be hard to type without vnc.

Comment: `127.0.0.1` will never connect to any other server, that's the IP of the calling server. Have you tried using the IP of the common server?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean? Can you give an example? but if you are pertaining to the ip address of rpi (192.168.1.x) I don't think I'm going in that direction? I want the website to be dynamic that I can change the ip but the name stays the same

Answer (score 0):

`127.0.0.1` is the IP of the system running the request. If you run that `file_get_contents` on any central server and access this using a browser, it will always access the server itself.

If you want to access any website on the system that is accessing the website, you need to use the IP address of the **client**, like `file_get_contents('http:/' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']  . '/name.php')`

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply. $device_name is still empty and takes a while to load. I also tried $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] but is still empty. Any idea why?

Comment: That depends :) What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Does this work when you access the URL directly? Does it work when using cURL or wget on the command line of the server?

Comment: If I echo the ip returned by $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] then type it directly on my browser it either takes too long to respond or returns empty string. I will give you an update later when I try other method

Comment: Is that IP the one you expect to see there? Sounds like a networking issue